# Multiplying elements in array not working in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to make a simple program in c++ that takes the price and number of items purchases, stores it in arrays, and then outputs the totals for each item in a tabular format. However, when I multiply the numbers in my code, I get totally strange answers! Can someone please enlighten me as to what's going on?

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    float price[4], tot[4];
    int amt[4];
    cout << "Please enter the price and amount of 4 items:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
        cout << "Price of item " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> price[i];
        cout << "Amount of item " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> amt[i];
        if (price[i] <= 0 || amt[i] <= 0) {
            cout << "Invalid Input Entry!\n";
            break;
        }
        tot[i] = price[i] * amt[i]; // I can't really see how I could have messed this up...
    }
    cout << "Total\t\tPrice\t\tAmount\n";
    cout << "-----\t\t-----\t\t------\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << "$" << fixed << cout.precision(2) << tot[i] << "\t\t$" << price[i] << "\t\t" << amt[i] << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

[image: program output]

Comment: This is what a debugger is meant for

Comment: The output you show does not belong to the program you show. (loop for 4 items and your output shows 8 items).

Comment: You may want to remove this: `cout.precision(2)`

Comment: @BitTickler yes I changed the number of loops later, but the values were still off.

Comment: What do the individual arrays contain?

Comment: I think you meant to use the manipulator [`setprecision(2)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) instead of calling the function [`cout.precision(2)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision). The results are correct except for a `6` (the first time) or `2` (the return value of `cout.precision(2)`) prepended.

Comment: With a simple debugging session you can verify if the values in your array make sense. If they do, the problem is in the ``cout << ...`` line. IOstream is not as intuitive as people try to make believe, once you start to use those stateful format modifiers like ``fixed`` and ``precision``. I never bothered to use them A simple ``printf()`` is much more intuitive to me.

Comment: @FredLarson But what about the first result (`$63.98`)?

Comment: Oh, the first time the return value was 6 (the default precision). Every time after that, you had already set it to 2 so it returned that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are outputting the return value of [`cout.precision(2)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) (which returns the previous precision, in this case `6` initially and then `2` afterwards) in front of each total price.

You need to either:

- not pass the return value of `cout.precision()` to `operator<<`:

  ```
  cout << "$" << fixed;
  cout.precision(2);
  cout << tot[i] << ...
  ```

  or, call `precision()` one time before entering the loop:

  ```
  cout.precision(2);
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      cout << "$" << fixed << tot[i] << "\t\t$" << price[i] << "\t\t" << amt[i] << endl;
  }
  ```
- use the [`std::setprecision()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) stream manipulator instead of calling `cout.precision()` directly:

  ```
  #include <iomanip>

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      cout << "$" << fixed << setprecision(2) << tot[i] << "\t\t$" << price[i] << "\t\t" << amt[i] << endl;
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  #include <iomanip>

  cout << setprecision(2);
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      cout << "$" << fixed << tot[i] << "\t\t$" << price[i] << "\t\t" << amt[i] << endl;
  }
  ```

---

On a side note, you should not use `\t` characters to control the formatting of your table.  Use stream manipulators like `std::setw()`, `std::left`, etc instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>    
using namespace std;

const int maxItems = 4;

string moneyStr(float amount)
{
    ostringstream oss;

    // in C++11 and later, you can replace this with std::put_money() instead:
    // http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_money
    //
    // oss << showbase << put_money(amount);
    oss << "$" << fixed << setprecision(2) << amount;

    return oss.str();
}

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    float price[maxItems], tot[maxItems];
    int amt[maxItems];
    int cnt = 0;

    cout << "Please enter the price and amount of " << maxItems << " items:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxItems; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Price of item " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> price[i];
        cout << "Amount of item " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> amt[i];
        if (price[i] <= 0 || amt[i] <= 0) {
            cout << "Invalid Input Entry!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        tot[i] = price[i] * amt[i];
        ++cnt;
    }

    cout << left << setfill(' ');
    cout << setw(16) << "Total" << setw(16) << "Price" << setw(16) << "Amount" << endl;
    cout << setw(16) << "-----" << setw(16) << "-----" << setw(16) << "------" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        cout << setw(16) << moneyStr(tot[i]) << setw(16) << moneyStr(price[i]) << setw(16) << amt[i] << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/494kbL)

Comment: An alternative would be to just call `cout.precision(2);` by itself (not using a stream insertion) once before doing the output.

Comment: This doesn't compile in Xcode. I get `Use of undeclared identifier "setprecision"`.

Comment: @FredLarson yes, that works, too. I added it to my answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Great answer, really explained things to me.